# How to create a distributed version of GNU make?

Tags: gnu-make

The main idea is that I have 3 slaves and each one execute a file and the master generate the make file , I need your help to know what are the libraries that I should use, and how can I detect the end of calculation of each process. Thanks.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want to distribute exactly. The work of creating the makefile? The work of compiling/etc. the project that the makefile manages? Something else? Does [`distcc`](https://code.google.com/p/distcc/) help here?

Comment: Also, when you say "slaves" and "master", are those different hosts?  Processes?  What does "execute a file" mean?

Comment: the slaves are different machines, each one execute a different code and another machine generate the make file

Comment: http://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/images/5/56/Sujet_sys_13.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a school assignment, I'm going to advise only on the choice of libraries.

So you need to execute remote commands and transfer data, this either requires starting a daemon on the remotes or leveraging an already running daemon. I think the latter is a better choice here, so you could use something like the [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) with keys for both transfer and command execution.

Then you need to analyze the dependencies between the rules, and execute the commands via the library in the right order (and degree of parallelism).